# How to use readerwriter lock per field

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking, mutex

Hello i have an object with some fields.I want this object to be thread safe.
This object will be accesed by two threads and changed.However The threads do not perform writes on the same fields

```
struct State
{
   public bool a;
   public bool b;
}
class LockedState{
 private State state;
 private readonly object @lock=new object();
 public bool A{
   get{ lock(@lock){ return this.state.a;}
   set{ lock(@lock){ this.state.a=value; }
}
public bool B{ ....}
}
```

My problem is that both threads change different fields of the object but both need to access all the fields.
My first try was  using a single `lock` for all the object, but i realised that it is not efficient since i do not want the thread that reads to wait for the lock when no one is writing on that field.

Should i be better off with `ReaderWriterLock` ?

```
class State {

        private const int TIMEOUT = 100;
        private ReaderWriterLock alock= new ReaderWriterLock();
        private ReaderWriterLock block= new ReaderWriterLock();

        private bool a;
        private bool b;

        public bool A {
            get {
                this.alock.AcquireReaderLock(TIMEOUT);
                return a;
            }
            set {
                this.alock.AcquireWriterLock(TIMEOUT);
                this.a= value;

            }
        }
        public bool B{
            get {
                this.block.AcquireReaderLock(TIMEOUT);
                return b;
            }
            set {
                this.block.AcquireWriterLock(TIMEOUT);
                this.b = value;

            }
        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether the fields are part of entire state and require to be mutual-consistent (in that case you'd need entire lock on all fields), or they are independent from each other (in that case if the fields are of primitive types like bool in your example, you don't need any synchronization at all as writing and reading operations of primitive type are guaranteed to be atomic).

Comment: Given 2 threads ;thread 1  writes in `a` and the other in `b`.Now both threads read both `a` and `b`.I would like for thread 1 to not require acquireing a lock when reading `b` if thread 2 is not writing in it and vice versa.I do not want the readers to acquire locks if there are no writes at that moment (regarding all fields)

Comment: The question isn't about threads but rather about `a` and `b`. Do they have any relationship to each other ?

Comment: They are flags that are used in a state machine.They have no direct relationship.They represent events or transitions.

Comment: In that case two questions: 1) if they are primitive types why would you need to protect them against the concurrent access? and 2) why are they part of the same class if they have no direct relationship (which indicates some low cohesion in your design) ?

Comment: As i said both threads take decisions upon reading both `a` and `b`.One thread though writes to `a` and the other to `b`.A scenario: one thread sets `a` the other reads `a` and `b` , does something and then sets `b`.

Comment: I still don't see why you need a synchronization for that. From what you described I can presume that any combination of `a` and `b` is valid from the consistency standpoint. The concurrency synchronization is about preventing inconsistent states which cannot happen in your case (or you omitted some details).